# Has anyone figured out how to install `moreutils` on Centos8?

Tags: centos8, moreutils

Has anyone figured out how to install `moreutils` on Centos8?

I'm getting this error:

```
[root@default-bento-centos-8 vagrant]# dnf install moreutils
Last metadata expiration check: 0:19:17 ago on Tue 17 Aug 2021 08:27:50 PM UTC.
Error:
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides perl(IPC::Run) needed by moreutils-0.63-1.el8.x86_64
  - nothing provides perl-IPC-Run needed by moreutils-0.63-1.el8.x86_64
(try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
  
[root@default-bento-centos-8 vagrant]# dnf -y --enablerepo=PowerTools install moreutils
Error: Unknown repo: 'PowerTools'
```

I have both the `epel-release` and `perl` packages installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The enable repo argument is case sensitive and powertools needs to be fully lower cased as opposed to Pascal Cased.

This works:

```
dnf install epel-release -y
dnf --enablerepo=powertools install moreutils -y
```